# What is the difference between import pyttsx3 as engine and engine = pyttsx3.init()?

Tags: python

So I am working on this project that requires text to speech, and one of the lines in the code is the following:

```
engine = pyttsx3.init()
```

and I was wondering what is the purpose of .init(). I suspected it was a way of inheriting the classes and methods of the pyttsx3 library so I tried to replace this line with:

```
import pyttsx3 as engine
```

which I thought would just change the name of the library, but the code didn't work anymore, so I would like to know what is the purpose of .init() please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The documentation of pyttsx3 explains this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
import pyttsx3 as engine
```

simply imports the library to be used in your code. The `as` keyword sets an alias word that can be used to call the module instead of `pyttsx3`

This

```
engine = pyttsx3.init()
```

> Gets a reference to an engine instance that will use the given driver. If the requested driver is already in use by another engine instance, that engine is returned. Otherwise, a new engine is created. The yielded response is saved to the variable `engine`.

Note that in order to call the `init()` method you must import the module first, i.e. with `import pyttsx3`

You can see more from the docs [here](https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html)